# How to run two where clauses inside a Join?

Tags: mysql, join

Please check the below code.

```
SELECT
  `order`.idorder
  , order_status_code.idorder_status_code
  , order_status_code.order_status_code
  , user.iduser
  , `order`.required_delivery_date
  , `order`.cancel
  , `order`.date_created
  , `order`.last_updated
  , COUNT(order_item.idorder_item) 
from
  `order` 
  INNER JOIN order_status_code 
    ON `order`.idorder_status_code = order_status_code.idorder_status_code 
  INNER JOIN user 
    ON `order`.iduser = user.iduser 
  INNER JOIN order_item 
    ON order_item.idorder = `order`.`idorder` 
WHERE
  `order`.iduser = 1
```

In here, I want the `COUNT(order_item.idorder_item)` to return the number of items under the `idorder`. In other words, if I run that SQL Part along, that would be like below

```
SELECT
  COUNT(`idorder_item`) 
from
  order_item 
where
  idorder = 1
```

How can I get this done in my main query?

Comment: You can add this "subquery" as a field in your query. You will have to put this sub-query between '(' and ')'.

Comment: @Luuk: Sorry, I didnt get your point.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `order`.idorder,
order_status_code.idorder_status_code,
order_status_code.order_status_code,
user.iduser,
`order`.required_delivery_date,
`order`.cancel,
`order`.date_created,
`order`.last_updated,
COUNT(order_item.idorder_item),
(SELECT COUNT(`idorder_item`) 
   from order_item 
   where idorder=1) as count_idorder_item
from `order`
INNER JOIN order_status_code ON `order`.idorder_status_code = order_status_code.idorder_status_code
INNER JOIN user ON `order`.iduser = user.iduser
INNER JOIN order_item ON order_item.idorder = `order`.`idorder`
WHERE `order`.iduser= 1
```